# classic asp - dropdown to select all dropdowns with the same value as the first dropdown

Tags: javascript, ajax, dynamic-data, html.dropdownlistfor, array-population

I have a primary drop down list that has three values:
1 - select
2 - Fail
3 - pass

the page is populated from the database, so here you could have anything from 1 to 50 dropdown to set the status of each record as fail or pass.

I would like to select 'fail' from the primary dropdown, any dropdown's that are populated from database should set to the selection i have made as being 'fail'

hope someone can help.
thank you
Yas

Comment: This isn't really a Classic ASP problem, it sounds like you need to look into Javascript and AJAX

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `javascript` or `jquery`.

`OnChange` of first dropdown, select all dropdown values accordingly.

### EDIT:

For your reference, I have prepared an example. Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/gtd6U/)**

### HTML:

```
<select class="dDown">
    <option value="select">select</option>
    <option value="Pass">Pass</option>
    <option value="Fail">Fail</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option value="select">select</option>
    <option value="Pass">Pass</option>
    <option value="Fail">Fail</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option value="select">select</option>
    <option value="Pass">Pass</option>
    <option value="Fail">Fail</option>
</select>
​
```

### JS:

```
$('.dDown').on("change", function() {
    $('select').not('.dDown').val(this.value);
});​
```

Comment: I'm using ajax with javascript, the code i've worked on in javascript, will only select the first one, but if there are more than one then nothing happens

Comment: @YasirH: For your reference, I have prepared a sample example. Check my updated answer.

Comment: thank you very much, this reference with the live demo is much appreciated.  I've tried that, but could'nt get it to work, as my code is using ajax, i will send you an example of what i'm doing.

Comment: @YasirH: yeah, that would be great.

Comment: I cant seem to add my code, its not allowing me to add it as a comment

Comment: <select class="dDown">
<option value="" selected onchange="setDropDown">Select</option>
<option value="935E010A6A424CAF9751FB51835A737B">Pass</option>
<option value="5F7327BCFC754108BAC244CDB8793DA7">Fail</option>
</select>

Comment: <select >
 <option value="Select">Select</option>
  <% if not rs4.eof and not rs4.bof then %>
  <% while not rs4.eof and not rs4.bof
   %>
   <option  <% if qualification = rs4("REF_DECODE") then%>selected="selected"<%end if%> value="<%=rs4("REF_DECODE")%>"><%=rs4("description")%></option>
   <% rs4.movenext
  wend %>
  <% end if %>
</select>





 function setDropDown(){
  $('.dDown').on("change", function() {
   $('select').not('.dDown').val(this.value);
  });
 }

Comment: @YasirH: Remove `onchange="setDropDown"` on all option tags. You should include jquery js file on the page then use this jquery code `$('.dDown').on("change", function() { $('select').not('.dDown').val(this.value); });`

Comment: Hi Siva, I'm not that familiar with jquery, i did include the jquery file to the file i'm working on and removed the onclick, but i'm getting an error ('mso.style' is null or not an object)

Comment: hi again, i'm having problems with this as jquery will not work due to the way the system has been built.  could someone help so that this code works on javascript